# Call Methode in process from c#-project

Tags: c#, methods, process, call, invoke

I want to call a public Methode(Send) in a process from my c# project!

This is the process with the Methode that i want to call :

```
    namespace Test123
    {
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        while(true)
        {
        }
    }

    public void Send()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Test");
    }
  }
}
```

I know how to get the process but not how to invoke the methode!

I already searched on other websites and i din´t found anything that helps me.

Comment: You want to call it from inside the loop? Tried Send();?

Answer (score 0):

Create a instance of the program in the static and call the method.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var p = new Program();
        while(true)
        {
             p.Send();
        }
    }

    public void Send()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Test");
     }
}
```

Comment: I want to invoke the Methode in a complete new c#-project(exe)!!! Not in the same project

Answer (score 0):

If your in the same Program class, you can just call the method. The other approach listed where you declare a new Program, would be needed if you were in a different class.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    while(true)
    {
     Send();
    }
}
```